# Solspace Shortcut for an entry

Tags: solspace

I've just added Solspace Shortcut to an install. I've tested some URLs from within the module itself and those seem to work fine.

I then added the fieldtype to the Channel and added a custom shortcut but it didn't resolve.

Now looking at the Shortcut control panel, I can see the shortcut but the URL is 'not set'.

Also, when I try to edit, I just get the control panel home page.

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like the full url for an entry isn't being set

Comment: We replied privately a few days ago. Did you receive our answer? If this issue is different, we can discuss in the private ticket you filed. Screenshots welcome :)